# Empty screen when Activity recreated

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I am loading contacts in SplashActivity :

```
private fun startMainActivity() {
        repository.loadContacts()
        handler.postDelayed({
            val intent =Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }, SPLASH_DELAY.toLong())
```

Here is my Repository class :

```
@Singleton
class ContactsRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val context: Context,
        private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider) {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>
        get() = _liveData

    fun loadContacts() {
        _liveData.value = Resource.Loading()
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE UNICODE ASC")
        Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<List<Contact>>
        { emitter -> emitter.onNext(ContactUtil.getContacts(cursor, context)) })
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .doOnComplete { cursor?.close() }
                .doFinally { compositeDisposable.clear() }
                .subscribe {
                    _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(it))
                }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }
}
```

In my MainFragment onCreateView I observe LiveData in viewModel :

```
                // Create the observer which updates the UI.
                final Observer<Resource<List<Contact>>> contactsObserver = resource -> {
                    if (resource instanceof Resource.Success) {
                        mContacts = ((Resource.Success<List<Contact>>) resource).getData();
                        mAdapter.setItems(mContacts, true);
                    }
                };
    
                // Observe the LiveData, passing in this fragment as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
                viewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, contactsObserver);
            }
```

Here is my ViewModel class :

```
class ContactsViewModel(repository: ContactsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData = repository.liveData
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>
        get() = _liveData

    /**
     * Factory for constructing ContactsViewModel with parameter
     */
    class Factory @Inject constructor(
            private val repository: ContactsRepository
    ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ContactsViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return ContactsViewModel(repository) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes when I resume MainFragment after a long time, I face with an empty screen without no data in RecyclerView (Maybe Container Activity is killed by OS for instance). My guess is `repository.liveData.value` returns null. It could be any other issue. I appreciate for your suggestions.

**Addenda** :

```
@Inject
ContactsViewModel.Factory mFactory;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ContactsViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, mFactory).get(ContactsViewModel.class);
            ViewDataBinding binding = FragmentContactsBinding.bind(root);
            binding.setVariable(BR.vm, viewModel);
            binding.setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner());
}
```

Full source code is available at : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/ui/ContactsFragment.java

Comment: It looks like the process has been terminated and the UI is restored from saved instance state. ViewModels will survive a configuration change but they will not be restored after process death (as described for example in [Options for preserving UI state](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states))  How does the Fragment "get" the ViewModel?

Comment: Thank You @BömachtBlau I have added ViewModel initialization to Addenda section in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that it is due to system initiated process death. As a result I add following line in init method of ViewModel to resolve this issue :

```
class ContactsViewModel(repository: ContactsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData = repository.liveData
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>
        get() = _liveData

    init {
        // Reload contacts in case of system initiated process death
        if(liveData.value == null) {
            repository.loadContacts()
        }
    }
}
```